# Is it possible before any college for me to get a short term job as a front end developer for experience?

Tags: work-experience, tech-industry, entry-level

I'm 17 years old, and I've been programming for several years now, and I'm hoping to make web development my career in the future. I'm wondering if there are any companies that would hire somebody like me so that I can get some money before college, and some experience for a future long term job. If it's possible, where would I look? Is there a specific position I should be seeking out?

Comment: When you say "short term" how long do you mean? Months? Years?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I'm thinking months, possibly up to a year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to your local community college career office and ask about places hiring interns. You're only a year or two younger than what they're expecting, and potentially more qualified than the average applicant. You won't make a ton, but having a mentor is potentially worth much more than another two dollars an hour at this point.

You can also pass out your resume to everyone you know, and ask them to take it to their friends. I receive several high-school student resumes per year, and they're usually on par with an average college student.

Comment: Yeah, money would be great but I know this is a short term job, so I know I won't make a fortune anyway. Experience and learning are more important to me.

What would I put on my resume, having never had a job before? Is there anything else I should know about applying as a high schooler?

Comment: You can list the skills you have--languages and tools you're familiar with. You can also list your education, and grades if they're good. Very.very short is better than irrelevant fluff.

Comment: Good answer. Family and families contacts can also be useful. I've given quite a few friends kids small jobs and a bit of training. They have usually proved to be cheap, short term grunts happy to have some cash in their pockets and a reference.